# can I bundle node_modules and do npm install from the bundle?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, offline

I am trying to setup Jenkins to do tsc but the build machine will not have internet access. To facilitate this I need to bundle the node_modules from another box with internet access and copy it over to the build machine and use this bundle to do npm install. In effect, I am trying to replicate maven's local repository structure to prevent npm install from accessing npm's repository. Is there a way to achieve this? From what I saw, npm pack facilitates deployment but not what I am trying to achieve, I need  node_modules so I can compile on the build machine. Also, it is a windows machine so no luck with offline-npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I switch between a linked npm dependency (in development) and an installed dependency (in staging/prod)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043423/how-can-i-switch-between-a-linked-npm-dependency-in-development-and-an-install)